# Simple groups with normal generating sets

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is it known that which finite non-abelian simple groups have a minimal generating set $S$ which is normal in $G$ (i.e. for every $g\in G$, we have $gSg^{-1}=S$)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. I meant non-abelian, but I did not write it. I edited the question. Thanks again

Comment: What do you mean by a minimal generating set?

Comment: @Derek Holt Sorry for not mentioning it. I meant minimal for inclusion between other generating sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that "minimal" means "minimal for inclusion among subsets generating $G$ as a group".

Fact: *No nonabelian group (finite or not, simple or not) has a minimal generating subset that is conjugacy-closed.*

Indeed, let a nonabelian group $G$ have such a subset $S$.
Since $G$ is nonabelian, there are two non-commuting elements $s,t$ in $S$. Then $sts^{-1}\in S$, since $S$ is conjugacy-closed. Also $sts^{-1}\in\{s,t\}$ is excluded because each implies that $s$ and $t$ commute. 
Hence, $sts^{-1}$ is a redundant generator, contradiction.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help

Comment: That's nice! I was trying to come up with a simple argument myself but everything I thought of was much more complicated and was probably using CFSG!